# java bad version number in .class file in browser

Tags: macos, applet, java

I am receiving  java bad version number in .class file when I try to open a simple applet in my browser (I have tried Firefox and Safari). My browsers stat that I am using a 1.5.X JRE, but my command line compiler is 1.6.x. I can't quite figure how to sync the two of these VM's, as I am not the most adept Mac user. I have tried the native software update feature, but there is no Java update available there. I've also tried updating in each browser, but I just get redirected to the Mac OS X Software Update feature.

Comment: Well trying to update the VM on your command line isn't going to be much use - 1.6 is the latest supported update from Apple. What browser versions are you using? You probably need to update to current versions of Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

while compiling files, you have to use **-target** option.

Example, **javac -target 1.5 [source file]**

More explanation is available at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 1):

For an Oracle JDK, you'd simply use the [cross-compilation options of `javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options).

Note that is important to specify `-source`, `-target` ***&*** `-bootclasspath` for the compilation.  That last one requires a JRE of the target version, to check the classes, methods & attributes used in the code actually existed in the target version.